# Paint on a CALayer on OSx

Tags: macos, drawing, calayer, draw, paint

I would like to know if it is possible to draw directly with a finger on a CALayer in OSX.

The context is this:

I have a NSVIEW with a CALayer on it (that represents an IMAGE, then myLayer.contents = (id)myImage) as sublayer of the view layer.

I have my own 3 method:

- TOUCH DOWN
- TOUCH MOVED
- TOUCH END

What is the best way to do this?

Many thanks, Sergio

Comment: the layer that contains the image, can't be something else.
I can move, scale and rotate the layer with 2 fingers, but when the user uses only 1 finger, layer doesn't move and the user should draw on it.

I use layer for performances.